# how to add a quick search capability to unordered list text?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a unordered list of names with a hidden overflow which makes them scrollable. each `li` has a nested image, a span with a first and last name text in it, and a `a href` link displaying a small icon after that. The list is very long.
How can i make this ul searchable by last name text (im assuming- by adding an input), so that it jumps to the name in the list according to the first letters in the last name ?
vanilla javascript option please

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><img class="makeIcon" src=""><span>FirstName LastName</span><a href="#"><img src="">
</a></li>
....many of these
</ul>
```

Comment: maybe you need this jquery plugin?
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seemed to work in my tests. Assuming your "ul" is given a unique id.

My vanilla js is a little rusty. I'm sure there are more succinct ways of doing this. I created a var for the "search term" (for testing purposes), but like you said - you'd get the value from an input.

```
<ul id="searchList">
    <li><img class="makeIcon" src=""><span>Marko Pollo</span><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
    <li><img class="makeIcon" src=""><span>Dr. Paul</span><a href="#"><img src=""></a></li>
</ul>


var ul_parent = document.getElementById('searchList');
var span_elements = ul_parent.getElementsByTagName("span");
var a_elements = ul_parent.getElementsByTagName("a");
var search_term = "Paul";
for (var i = 0, len = span_elements.length; i < len; i++ ) {
     var lName = span_elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\w+\s(\w+)$/, function(_, $1){
           return $1;
     });
     if(search_term == lName){
        console.log('found match');
        a_elements[i].focus();
        // once a match is found, return false out or do something else.
     }
} // if you reach this point, you can add an else{} and alert user no matches
```

I didn't add this, but you might want to go this route to keep it case agnostic: .toLowerCase() , so, something like:

```
search_term.toLowerCase() == lName.toLowerCase()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the content of the span tag or a data attribute.

But you SHOULD use jQuery with show/hide method and change event on your input.

It only take few line to code, but some plugin could do it.

jQuery Autocomplete change the way it is displayed.